# How to stop tiptap Link from propagating after insertion?

Tags: tiptap

After inserting a link onto selected text in my editor using tiptap, the link propagation continues when I type more text. How do I stop propagation?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is quite simple.
You can extend the Link mark when setting up the editor in your code like this:

```
this.editor = new Editor({
  element: this.editorRef,
  extensions: [
    //...
    Link.extend({
      inclusive: false,
    })
    //...
  ]
});
```

`inclusive: false` makes sure that links don't include the final position of the cursor.